# How to create visual studio projects that use LLVM

Tags: visual-studio, llvm

I'm trying to use LLVM to implement a compiler for a toy language. Something like the [Kaleidoscope Tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html). I'm using Visual Studio on 64 bit Windows.

I've managed to build LLVM and clang using VS, but now I want to use the LLVM libraries in my own project. It seems like a silly question but how to I do this? What compiler options do I need? What libraries should I link with etc. etc.

As far as I can see this isn't covered anywhere in the LLVM documentation although I could have easily missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered `llvm-config` which is designed to solve the problems I'm having. It often seems to give incorrect information (for instance `llvm-config --includedir` is wrong) but it at least gives me a list of libraries to link with.

I suppose I could also use CMake to generate project files, but CMake seems to be difficult to learn from free resources.